# Follow a record via community login, not visible in salesforce

Tags: community, chatter

We are developing an app that leverages communities, and we're allowing users to unfollow/follow records to later tie into push notifications.  I can create the EntitySubscription record for the user when they choose to follow a record.  This requires the EntitySubscription to set a NetworkId (which is the CommunityId).  This is working fine.

However, it looks as if the **standard salesforce web interface** for employees does not see any followers if the NetworkId is not null.  Is there a way to change this behavior in salesforce web (not community login, standard login)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chatter in Communities and Chatter in your internal org are two separate entities with a wall between them. If I understand your question this is the root of your problem.

You'll notice, for example, that a Chatter user in the community does not exist as a chatter user in your internal org. Same with Chatter Groups.

So if a community user is 'following' a record via chatter, that is being tracked within the Community Chatter, and will not be reflected in the internal org's Chatter.

I would imagine that if you wanted to track your Communities' EntitySubscriptions within your internal org, you'd have to design a custom interface to show it. You couldn't rely on Chatter's interface as the community users aren't even listed in your internal org.

Comment: Appreciate the response and what you're saying makes sense.  Seems like a limitation because if an internal/employee user that logs into the community to interact w/ community members follows a record that way (think mobile app, same app for employees and customers) it isn't visible in the internal web interface of salesforce.

Comment: How do your internal users access the community? It sounds like maybe you're using community licenses to give them access? If that's the case it's unnecessary, as your internal users should be able to access the community from within their internal SF interface, as long as you have the Global Header activated (https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000CyhAAAS)

Comment: We aren't doing what you're thinking.  Our employees can go to the community portal page (or our mobile app) and they choose the link for employee login.  They authenticate as you would expect but their came in through the community site page, so the have a access to community chatter groups, etc.

Comment: Well, your internal users at least have options when it comes to how they follow records. If they follow a record while they are logged in to the community as themselves (ie you didn't create a separate community user for them), then the record would be followed within the community's chatter. If they are logged in to their internal org and they follow the same record, they will see it in the internal chatter interface. Your community users, on the other hand, don't have that flexibilty AFAIK.